# On lattice points "far inside" convex lattice polygons

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a convex lattice polygon with $n$ vertices and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of all lattice points inside $\mathcal{P}$. For every $n \geq 5$, does there exist a point in $\mathcal{L}$ such that it also lies in the convex polygon bounded by (all) the diagonals of $\mathcal{P}$? How many such points are there? (//By diagonals I mean of course the lines different from the sidelines of the polygon which are connecting two vertices of $\mathcal{P}$.)

I proved a while ago that for $n=5$ there is such a point in $\mathcal{L}$. I also managed to show this now for $n \geq 6$ using a similar argument, yet it got more involved and I still need to check for potential bugs. Any ideas for the general case?

Comment: I suspect there are simple counterexamples for n=6, so I may be misunderstanding something.  Can you say more about what interior region is supposed to have a lattice point?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.11.17

Comment: What do you mean by "the convex pentagon bounded by (all) the diagonals of P"? usually the do not bound a pentagon.

Comment: Yes he does, in the first line.

Comment: @Fedor: Sorry, it should have read "the convex polygon bounded by all the diagonals of $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: I was thinking of two diagonals of a 3x1 rectangle, cut off center by a diagonal of a perpendicular 4x1 rectangle, as some diagonals for my cex.  Perhaps you can tell me how this fits in with your result?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.11.17

Comment: Also, the smallest convex lattice pentagon I can think of has only one interior lattice point, and that lies on the boundary of the interior pentagon.  Does your result include such a case?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2011.11.17

Comment: I am still having difficulty understanding the phrase, "the convex polygon bounded by all the diagonals of $P$."  In general, there is
no convex polygon bounded by *all* the diagonals, if by "bounded" you mean, "forming the boundary of."  There are many convex polygons, each bounded by a subset of the diagonals...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n=5$, this has been shown by Eppstein:
[D. Eppstein, Happy endings for flip graphs, Journal of Computational Geometry 1 (2010), no. 1, 3--28.](https://jocg.org/index.php/jocg/article/view/2969)

For odd $n>5$, one could consider the polygon bounded by the longest diagonals.
It may be defined as the intersection of the half-planes containing $(n+1)/2$ vertices of $P$.
For $n=9$, this intersection may be empty (for example, if the nine vertices form three triples and each of the triples is placed very close to a vertex of a regular triangle).
For $n=7$, this intersection is non-empty. However, it may be free of lattice points:
take, for example, the polygon $P$ with vertices
$[0,1],
[1,0],
[2,0],
[3,2],
[3,3],
[1,3],
[0,2]$.

[image: a lattice 7-gon with no lattice points in the inner polygon]

Comment: It seems that JOCG changed their website, the link in the post no longer works - this seems to be the new location: https://jocg.org/index.php/jocg/article/view/2969. (Of course, since full details are given in the answer, the paper can be easily found [in many various places](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%20Eppstein+Happy+endings+for+flip+graphs).)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the link in the answer (interestingly, they only changed the number in the end).